# Evaluating checkboxes and Passing variable through url

Tags: forms, url, pagination

im need some help regarding my application. Im developing this application for managing a small inventory.

There are approximately 1000 items in the inventory. These items are lend to customers for a period.

Since i don't want to display 1000 items in a single page, i used simple php pagination for displaying 50 items per page. Using checkboxes, my code gives user the ability to check particular items and click a button to submit the form. This form receive the values of checked items and takes the user to a print screen. On the print screen, the checked items are displayed.
In brief, user selects some items and a form is submitted. No problem occurs upto this point.

Now the problem is, when the user selects items which are on different pages, (say, item no. 5 on page 1 and item no. 51 on page 2), only item no. 2 is submitted to the form and, on the print screen, only item no. 2 is displayed.

To get around this, im trying to pass an array variable through URL.

im trying to pass the array variable through a link(Not by form), so that i can concatenate this array variable to the checkbox variable before the form is submitted. That way, wen the form will be submitted, it will process all the items and it will display all items on print screen which might have been checked on different pages.

I also tried using AJAX pagination, but it did not help.

here is my code, i guess its quite long, but i had to post it, to explain my problem.

Your help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.  I tried to find a solution on the web. Could not find something very relevant.

```
<div class="row">
<form action="confirm_checkout_items_multiple.php" method="POST">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 page-heading-adjust">
<?php
// this is for counting no. of pages
$queryCount = "SELECT * FROM inventory_table WHERE Checkedout!='1'";
<?php
$resultQueryCount = mysql_query($queryCount);
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($resultQueryCount);
$pageCount = $rowCount/50;
$pageCount = ceil($pageCount);
$page = "";
$pagenum = "";
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
  $page = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
$pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $pageCount) { 
$pagenum = $pageCount; 
}
if($page=="" || $page=="1") {
  $pageone = 0;
}
 else {
  $pageone = ($page*50)-50;
}
?>
$query="SELECT * FROM inventory_table WHERE Checkedout!='1' LIMIT $pageone, 50";
<?php
$result=mysql_query($query);                           
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
$previous = $pagenum - 1;
$CF = 5;
if(isset($page) && $page>1) {
$paginationCtrls .= '<ul class="pagination"><li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].?page='.$previous.'&CF='.$CF.'">&laquo;</a></li>';
} else {
    $paginationCtrls .= '<ul class="pagination">';
}
// Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++){
    //for($a=)
    //$a = 51;
    //$b = 100;
    //for($a=51;)
    //$c = '('.$a.'-'.$b.')';
    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$i.'&CF='.$CF.'">'.$i.'</a>    </li>';
if($i >= $pagenum+24){
  break;
    }
}
// This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
if ($pagenum != $pageCount) {
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$next.'&CF='.$CF.'">&raquo</a></li></ul> ';   
}
?>
```

#### Total number of pages:

```
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" name="checkout_temporary_multiple" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout selected Items</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 text-center page-heading-adjust">
                    <h3>Switch to: <a href="" class="btn btn-default disabled">Multiple Checkout</a> <a href="checkout_temporary_single.php" class="btn btn-default">Single Checkout</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 page-heading-adjust-2">
                    <?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">S. No.</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Code</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Description</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Colour</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Size</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Location</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading">Catalogue</th>
                                    <th class="nrml-heading text-center">Checkout</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php

                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $id = $row['id'];
                                    $Code = $row['Code'];
                                    $Description = $row['Description'];
                                    $Colour=$row['Colour'];
                                    $Size = $row['Size'];
                                    $Location=$row['Location'];
                                    $Catalogue=$row['Catalogue'];


                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Code; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Description; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Colour; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Size; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Location; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $Catalogue; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use session variables?
at the very beginning of the page, something like this

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
$getstring = $_SESSION['checkedItems'];
?>
```

and each time the user moves to a new page

```
$_SESSION['checkedItems'] = 'url get string here';
```

then dump the string on the end of the url as a get variable on form submission.

```
function itemchecked(){

//use an if block to see if the item clicked was checked or unchecked
// then change the getstring variable accordingly

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sessionUpdate.php",
      data: getstring,
      success: function(){
          // Do what you want to do when the session has been updated
      }
   });

};
```

in the sessionUpdate php, retrive the string and write it to a session variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i would definitely try session variables, but im actually trying to figure out how to check/evaluate/find out, which of the variables are checked in the list, without submitting the form.

When form is submitted, i evaluate checked items like this: 
$id = $_POST['selector'];

How do i find out which items are checked without submitting the form.
Once i find out, how to evaluate the checked items without submitting form, i can easily assign them to an array and pass the variable through url.